# Proving an inequality.

Tags: inequality

I have stuck in the middle of a problem and I don't know whether or not the following inequality is true.

$$\sum_{i=0}^{[n\,t]} \Bigl(1-\frac{i}{n\,t}\Bigr)^{n-1}>t$$

Assuming that $n$ is a natural number and $t$ is a positive real number and $[x]$ is the floor function.

Comment: Please show (1) your work and (2) what $[x]$ means (I presume floor function, but there really is no standard notation for that).

Comment: The cases $n=1$ and $n=2$ are easy. For $n>2$ I can prove $\dots>t/2$. Numerical evidence suggests that $\dots>t+1/2$.